# get a variable passed to my controller from a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple model I am using for a search page to do some validation:

```
        public class Search {
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Tag Number")]
        [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Tag must be a number")]
        public int HouseTag { get; set; }
```

i then have a simple view with a textbox and a submit button:

```
@model Search

@{
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";
}   

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Inquiry", FormMethod.Get)){
    @Html.LabelFor(m =>m.HouseTag)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.HouseTag, new { type = "Search", autofocus = "true", style = "width: 200px", @maxlength = "6" })

    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit"/>
```

my controller is expecting a parameter of an id:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search(int id){
        ViewBag.Tag = id;
        return View();
    }
```

when i execute it with a number i get a null value being passed to the controller, causing things to blow up. I am using the model to control some of the properties of the search box for validation. I used to just have @Html.TextBox and it returned fine, but now that ive added the model, it doesnlt return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your parameter to a type of Search and then access the property in your action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(Search model){
    ViewBag.Tag = model.HouseTag;
    return View();
}
```

If it were me I'd make this a HttpPost or create a seperate action for this form so I wouldn't see the HouseTag text in the URL..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Inquiry", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HouseTag)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HouseTag, new { type = "Search", autofocus = "true", style = "width: 200px", @maxlength = "6" })

    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit" />
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(Search model){
    ViewBag.Tag = model.HouseTag;
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting a parameter named id and you are passing HouseTag as the name of that parameter you should rename id to houseTag inside the Search method.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things going on here.  First you are going to want to split your Get and Post actions.  Also forms are only used in conjunction with POST's.  You also don't need to name your action or controller unless you are sending the post to a different controller or action then the GET.

This is the get.  It renders the form on the page.  You don't need to put [HttpGet] on there, it is the default.

```
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The following is going to post the form back to the server.  the model binder will wire up the html form fields with your view model.  since you have validators on the view model, you'll want to check that the model state is valid and re-show the view with the associated errors.  You will need to add an @Html.ValidationMessageFor(...) into your view so that you actually see those errors.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Inquiry(Search search)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(search);
        }

        //so something with your posted model.
    }
```